# Is there a way to specify parameters for included methods in TestNG suite.xml?

Tags: xml, parameters, testng, suite

I'm writing a suite.xml for an own testframework based on TestNG. My xml file looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Suite" parallel="methods">
  <test name="NewTest">
  <parameter name="BROWSER" value="Chrome"></parameter>
  <classes>
   <class name="hm.NewTest">
     <methods>
        <include name="test"></include>
        <include name="test2"></include>
        <include name="test3"></include>
        <include name="test4"></include>
     </methods>
   </class>
 </classes>
 </test>
 </suite>
```

The parameter "BROWSER" is now specified for the complete test. But i need an own parameter for each of the included methods. Does anyone knows a solution?

Comment: This is a common design error of putting the selenium parameters as test parameters. Test parameters are for logical variables in the test, e.g user information to log in with, or a test to search for in a table. The driver options are technical implementation details and should be handled through your framework. The test should have no idea what browser it's running on or why. Browser compatibility issues aren't behavioral bugs, they're delivery bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this rather than assigning parameters in test suite xml you can assign parameters for your tests individually . for that you don't have to add each parameter in suite.xml .

```
@Parameters({ "datasource", "jdbcDriver" })
@test
public void sampleTest(String ds, String driver) {
// your test method
}
```

Hope this will help you [1](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters)

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters

Comment: Can you please tell us structure of TestNG.xml file which will pass same no of parameter with different values for each of the included methods?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason testng 6.4 and up no longer supports parameter inside the  method.

But if you revert back to 6.3 i think, is the last version that supported that.
I have same issue and recall that it used to work in our framework, so i started reverting back one version at a time. Why they took it out is beyond me.

With 6.3 you could do:

```
<methods>
        <include name="test">
          <parameter name="Firefox"/>
        </include>
        <include name="test2">
           <parameter name="Chrome"/>
        </include>
        <include name="test3">...</include>
        <include name="test4">...</include>
</methods>
```

and somewhere with listener call

```
iTestContext.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameters()
```

Hope it helps. If too late for you, maybe good info for someone else.

Edit: I LIED! You can still get it with latest testng ;)

```
iTestResult.getMethod().findMethodParameters(iTestContext.getCurrentXmlTest())
```